# How to left and right strip at the same time?

Tags: bash

I use `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` to remove prefix and postfix of string.

```
$ x=2012-hello.jpg
$ y=${x#*-}
$ z=${y%.*}
$ echo $z
hello
```

How can I do them at once instead of two.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible with parameter expansion, but it is possible with regular expression matching:

```
x=2012-hello.jpg
[[ $x =~ .*-(.*)\.jpg ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using `sed` instead of parameter expansion:

```
x=2012-hello.jpg
$ z="$(sed -e 's/.*-\(.*\)\..*/\1/' <<<"$x")"
$ echo "$z"
hello
```